# Updating a value in firebase with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function to get and display data from firebase, create buttons to change the value of 'read' from a book

```
function readBooksSaved() {
  firebase.database().ref('books').orderByChild('author').on('value', function(snapshot){

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      //alert(childData)

      let key = childSnapshot.key
      let b_title = childSnapshot.val().title;
      let b_author = childSnapshot.val().author;
      let b_page = childSnapshot.val().page;
      let b_read = childSnapshot.val().read;

      const u = document.querySelector('#container-li');
      let a = document.createElement('li');
      let b = document.createElement('li');
      let c = document.createElement('li');
      let d = document.createElement('li');
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      const button = document.createElement('a')
      const button2 = document.createElement('a')

      a.innerHTML = `<strong>Title:</strong> ${b_title}`;
      b.innerHTML = `<strong>Author:</strong> ${b_author}`;
      c.innerHTML = `<strong>Pages:</strong> ${b_page}`;
      button.innerHTML = `<a href="">Erase</a>`;
      
      if (b_read) {
        b_read = 'Yes'
        status = 'Unread'}
        else {
        b_read = 'No' }

      d.innerHTML = `<strong>Read</strong> ${b_read}`;

      button2.innerHTML = `<a class="btn btn-primary" id="change">${status}</a>`;
      
      u.appendChild(a).classList.add("bg-info");
      u.appendChild(b).classList.add("list-group-item");
      u.appendChild(c).classList.add("list-group-item");
      u.appendChild(d).classList.add("list-group-item");
      u.appendChild(button).classList.add("list-group-item");
      u.appendChild(button2).classList.add("list-group-item");

      let change_bt = document.querySelector('#change')
      change_bt.addEventListener('click', changeReadStatus(key, b_read))
  });
});
}

function changeReadStatus(key, b_read){
  let db_firebase = firebase.database().ref('books/'+ key)
  if (b_read) {
    db_firebase.update({'/read': false})
  }
  else {
    db_firebase.update({'/read': true})
  }
}
```

Everytime the page loads it enters to the changeReadStatus function and when click on the button the value or 'read' doesn't change on firebase. ¿Could you help me, please? I think I have some errors on the code but I have try without success.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function changeReadStatus(key, b_read){
    let db_firebase = firebase.database().ref('books/'+ key);
    if(b_read){
        db_firebase.update({
        'read': true
        });
    }
    else{
        db_firebase.update({
        'read': false
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) function, like this:

```
function changeReadStatus(key, b_read){
  let db_firebase = firebase.database().ref('books/'+ key);
  db_firebase.set({'read': b_read});
}
```